# Class not found exception in jsf hibernate application

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf-2

Just I started learning hibernate with jsf, a sample applications created by myself. I am getting class not found exception(i.e POJO class ) and below are the my code, please help me in coding.

**HibernateBean is my POJO class**

```
package com.bectran.employee;

public class HibernateBean {

    private int id;
    private String userName;
    private String passwd;

    public HibernateBean() {

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPasswd() {
        return passwd;
    }

    public void setPasswd(String passwd) {
        this.passwd = passwd;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


}
```

**Connection class**

```
package com.bectran.employee;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class LoginMain {

    public LoginMain() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public static void save1(){
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml"); 
        ServiceRegistryBuilder registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
        registry.applySettings(cfg.getProperties());
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = registry.buildServiceRegistry();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        HibernateBean hb=new HibernateBean();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(hb);
        System.out.println("Object saved successfully.....!!");
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
    }
}
```

**`hbm file`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.bectran.employee.HibernateBean"  table="logintable">
        <id name="id" column="id">
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="userName" type="String" column="username"  />
        <property name="passwd" type="String" column="pass"  />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**cfg.xml file**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<!-- Generated by MyEclipse Hibernate Tools. -->
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <mapping resource="com/bectran/employee/HibernateBean.hbm.xml" ></mapping>
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**home.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:body>
        <h1><marquee>Login Page</marquee></h1>

        <h:form>
            UserName : <h:inputText value="#{userBean.userName}" />
            Password : <h:inputSecret value="#{userBean.passwd}" />
            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{loginBean.save1}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check out the page on [how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could describe the desired behavior you're having trouble with.

Comment: What tutorial are you using, please use a newer one. Both jsf and hibernate work with annotations these days instead of config files. And an issue is in 99% pf the cases not jsf AND hibernate related, certainly not PrimeFaces. Narrow down the problem. And post where the CNFE occurs and what it is is required to.

Comment: And both hibernate and jsf are available in more recent versions to

Comment: Post the exception.

Comment: I got a solution myself, I didn't give correct root path for hibernate.cfg.xml file. After saving configuration file to src folder it is working now